# What is the most optimal way to bulk insert and update data using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel command that searches data from a SQL Server database and inserts each row (or updates it if already exists) in a MySQL database.

This is the code as it currently works:

First, the search of rows from SQL Server:

```
 $etiquetas = DB::connection('delisur_picking')
            ->table('deli_eti_correl')
            ->where('correl', '>', $lastLabel)
            ->orderBy('correl', 'asc')
            ->get()
            ->chunk(100);
```

And then the inserts and/or updates:

```
$i = 0;
$numins=0;
$numupd=0;
$tot=0;
$locations=DB::connection("mysql")->table("locations")->select("id", "code")->get();
$alocations=array();
foreach($locations as $l){
    $alocations[$l->id]=$l->code;
}
foreach ($etiquetas as $chunk) {
    $i = $i + 1;
    Log::info('Cargando '.$i.' chunks de '.count($etiquetas));
    $arrlabelI=array();
    $arrlabelU=array();
    foreach ($chunk as $etiqueta) {
        $tot++;
        $label=array();
        $labelExists=DB::connection("mysql")->table("labels")->where("correlative", $etiqueta->correl)->exists();
        $locationid=array_search($etiqueta->origen, $alocations);
        $label["cod_prod"]=$etiqueta->cod_prod;
        $label["nom_prod1"]=trim($etiqueta->nom_prod1);
        $label["nom_prod2"]=trim($etiqueta->nom_prod2);
        $label["q_caja"]=$etiqueta->q_caja;
        $label["fec_elab"]= $etiqueta->fec_elab;
        $label["lote"]= $etiqueta->lote;
        $label["fec_sys"]= $etiqueta->fec_sys;
        $label["actual_location"]= trim($etiqueta->origen) == '' ? null : ($locationid!==false ? $locationid : null);
        if($labelExists){
            $arrlabelU[$etiqueta->correl]=$label;
            Log::info("Correlativo marcado para actualizacion: $etiqueta->correl");                
        }else{
            $label["correlative"]=$etiqueta->correl;
            $arrlabelI[]=$label;
            Log::info("Correlativo marcado para insercion: $etiqueta->correl");
        }
    }

    DB::connection('mysql')->table("labels_alt")->insert($arrlabelI);
    $numins+=count($arrlabelI);
    foreach($arrlabelU as $idx => $row){
        DB::connection('mysql')->table("labels")->where("correlative", $idx)->update($row);
        $numupd++;
    }
}
```

The label table is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `labels` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `correlative` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cod_prod` VARCHAR(191) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `nom_prod1` VARCHAR(191) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `nom_prod2` VARCHAR(191) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `q_caja` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fec_elab` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `lote` VARCHAR(191) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `fec_sys` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `actual_location` VARCHAR(191) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

For each chunk it takes 1/2 second to populate the arrays `$alabelsI` and `$alabelsU` (given the number of rows per chunk, that is an approximated total of 50 seconds) and a half of a second to insert the data in `$alabelsI`

Questions:

1. Is there a faster way to populate the arrays?
2. Due to client's restrictions, we cannot modify the existing tables in the MySQL database. As a consequence, I cannot define the correlative column as an unique key, which is required in MySQL in order to use the Laravel's `upsert` function. If I cannot use `upsert`, is there a more optimal way than the code above to insert or update the data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the _generated_ SQL for the `INSERT` or upsert.

Comment: "we cannot modify the existing tables in the MySQL database"  If that means that you cannot even add an `INDEX`, then you should look for another job.

Comment: We cannot because the client doesn't allow it. That's why I wrote "due to client's restrictions". We know how to do it.
Also, the generated SQL is too long because is an insert of up to 100 rows and we use eloquent for this.

Comment: A "batch insert" like that is much faster than 100 single-row inserts.  (I do not speak Laravel, so I cannot address that side of the Question.)

Comment: The ```insert``` function in Laravel  allows insert one or more rows in one table. This allows, in my case, insert up to 100 rows with a single call instead of doing it with one call per row.

Comment: Back to the title "most optimal way"...  If that is asking about "fastest way to insert", I need to see the generated SQL to advise.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The fastest form we found to do what we needed is:

1. Create a new table (named labels_alt) that is a copy of labels
2. Replace the foreach loop above for the following one. This code inserts all rows in the new table

```
foreach ($etiquetas as $chunk) {
    $i = $i + 1;
    Log::info('Cargando '.$i.' chunks de '.count($etiquetas));
    $arrlabelI=array();
    foreach ($chunk as $etiqueta) {
        $tot++;
        $label=array();
        $locationid=array_search($etiqueta->origen, $alocations);
        $label["cod_prod"]=iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $etiqueta->cod_prod);
        $label["nom_prod1"]=iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', trim(iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', "$etiqueta->nom_prod1")));
        $label["nom_prod2"]=iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', trim(iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', "$etiqueta->nom_prod2")));
        $label["q_caja"]=iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $etiqueta->q_caja);
        $label["fec_elab"]= iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $etiqueta->fec_elab);
        $label["lote"]= iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $etiqueta->lote);
        $label["fec_sys"]= iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $etiqueta->fec_sys);
        $label["actual_location"]= trim($etiqueta->origen) == '' ? null : ($locationid!==false ? $locationid : null);
        $label["correlative"]= iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $etiqueta->correl);
        $arrlabelI[]=$label;
    }

    DB::connection('mysql')->table("labels_alt")->insert($arrlabelI);
    $numins+=count($arrlabelI);
}
$pstmt=DB::connection("mysql")->getPDO()->prepare("call insertLabels()");
$pstmt->execute();
```

3. Create a stored procedure in the database that makes the inserting and updating in labels:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertLabels`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE icorrelative, qcaja BIGINT(20);
    DECLARE codprod, nomprod1, nomprod2, ilote VARCHAR(191);
    DECLARE fecelab, fecsys DATETIME; 
    DECLARE createdat, updatedat TIMESTAMP;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE ext_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT labels_alt.correlative, labels_alt.q_caja, labels_alt.cod_prod, labels_alt.nom_prod1, labels_alt.nom_prod2, labels_alt.lote, labels_alt.fec_elab, labels_alt.fec_sys, labels_alt.created_at 
    FROM labels_alt INNER JOIN labels ON labels_alt.correlative=labels.correlative;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    INSERT INTO labels (correlative, q_caja, cod_prod, nom_prod1, nom_prod2, lote, fec_elab, fec_sys, created_at, updated_at) SELECT correlative, q_caja, cod_prod, nom_prod1, nom_prod2, lote, fec_elab, fec_sys, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM labels_alt a NATURAL LEFT JOIN labels b WHERE b.correlative IS NULL;
    OPEN ext_cursor;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH ext_cursor INTO icorrelative, qcaja, codprod, nomprod1, nomprod2, ilote, fecelab, fecsys, createdat; 
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        UPDATE labels SET q_caja=qcaja, cod_prod=codprod, nom_prod1=nomprod1, lote=ilote, fec_elab=fecelab, fec_sys=fecsys, created_at=createdat, updated_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE correlative=icorrelative;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ext_cursor;
    TRUNCATE labels_alt;
END
```

In a nutshell, is to minimize the execution of the SQL statements from Laravel as much as possible by moving said statements to a stored procedure.